# How do I hide translation vertical tab programmatically?

Tags: forms, 8, i18n-l10n

I would like to hide the *Translation* vertical tab. I tried with `$form['content_translation']['#access'] = FALSE;` but it seems not working.

How do I remove that vertical tab?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you give a little hint, under which route this can be found?

Comment: @ssibal, sure. I added an article but I would like that my users can read it in English. I clicked the translate tab where I can add translations. For example: mydomain.tld/en/node/2581/translations/add/hu/en

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.

In core\modules\content_translatio\src\ContentTranslationHandler.php, there is an `entityFormAlter()` method, which adds this vertical tab. It seems that this method is executed after your code. I would try changing the weight of your module (so your code will run later).

(I found this looking for the *If you made a significant change* string in core; doing so, I found where the translation tab was coming from.)